# Simplenews unsubscribe link shows a 404 Page

Tags: emails

In my Newsletter the unsubscribe URL which is inserted by a token, returns a 404 page.
The URL of my Link is:

http://www.mysite.info/newsletter/confirm/remove/

What could be the issue?

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7??

Comment: If Drupal 6, what version

Answer (score 1):

There are many issue thread on simplenews about this issue.

- [Simplenews 404 issues](http://drupal.org/project/issues/simplenews?text=404%20page%20not%20found&status=All)

Currently the only supported version of simplenews is version 6.x-1.3 (May 21st 2010).   Most of the issues have patches that are commit to 6.x-2.x-dev and 6.x-2.0-alpha2.  You might want to upgrade.  If you don't, then you will need to apply one or multiple patches to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the Simplenews module, the default is to provide a subscriber with an unsubscribe link when they receive an email from a posting i.e. creating of an issue.  This process of appending the unsubscribe link is a default action of the module.  The typical link which is appended to all sent newsletters includes the standard text, i.e. click here to unsubscribe.

The link provided to the user in the email is similar to

```
http://www.mysite.info/newsletter/confirm/remove/2210afaa624t1
```

... where the id at the end is the one linked to the email address when the user first subscribed.

If you don't include the ID on the URL, then you will get the 404 error.

I have not seen a feature that lets a user come to the site and enter an email address and then click a remove button.  I'm guessing someone would have to add this as a module if desired.

Comment: I'm getting the 404 with the full link you mention.

Comment: Is the link you are trying from an email that was created and sent by the SimpleNews Module.  The link I provided above was only a sample from one of our implementations.

If you Send a newsletter out with SimpleNews to a valid email address, then the link at the bottom of the email should have an unsubscribe link similiar to the one above.

Comment: Indeed, the link from an email created and sent by the SimpleNews Module.